# how to fix insert error using php and postgreSQL on apache Tomcat

Tags: php, postgresql, insert

can someone help me please
i am using postgresql on insert comment in a table named comment_user but when i click on the submit but i only get my  html form back.
it doesn't give me any error but the insertion doesn't work.
this is my form.

```
<?php

    $db = pg_connect( "host = localhost port = 5432  dbname = essaouira_tourisme user = postgres password = 0000");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment_value = $_POST['comment_value'];

        if ($username && $email && $comment_value) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO comment_user (username,email,comment_value) VALUES(
        '".$username."','".$email."','".$comment_value."')";
            $result = pg_query($db,$query);

            if ($result) {
                echo "<h2 color = 'red'>Votre commentaire a été enregistré avec succès</h2>";
                header('location:../../index.html');
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "veuillez remplir tous les champs";
        }

    }
    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Form Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="commentaire.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contact-title">
        <h2>vos commentaires nous seront utiles</h2>
        <h3>Donnez vos avis</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-form">
        <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="commentaire.php">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="votre pseudo" required><br>

            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="votre courriel" required><br>

            <textarea name="comment_value" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="votre commentaire ici" required></textarea><br>

            <input type="submit" class="form-control submit"  name= "submit" value="ENVOYER">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `try/catch` block in order to print the error

Comment: what `var_dump($_POST)` says? are you sure that all the values are there?

Comment: also, try to put `echo pg_last_error($db);` both right after db connect and query execution. currently, you are not handling any errors.

Comment: No there is another column which will be completed by the admin after loading the records on his interface. so It will be filled by null by default

Comment: Just an observation: you should consider using bind parameters instead of just concating the query as a string, with no treatment at all.